# .htaccess file to redirect all page request to Controller.php with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect page request through a Controller.php by appending the request parameter with the page name

When I enter below Url,

```
http://www.mydomain.com/view/pages/admin/stock-maintenance.php
```

It should route to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/control/Controller.php
```

with a parameter called `stock-maintenance=y` which means `<page-name=y>`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say:

`RewriteRule ^view/pages/admin/([^\.]+)\.php$ /control/Controller.php?$1=y`